# Disable opening 'new file' when opening app

Tags: macos, applications

In Catalina, but also in the previous MacOS, when I open applications such as Word, Excel, etc, or most applications, a new file is opened automatically by default.

Is there a way to disable this? **I would like to just open the application without opening a new file**.

Comment: Normally people had an issue with recently opened files. Just want to confirm before providing the solution, in your case, it opens a new file (blank document in Word, blank Worksheet in Excel), am I correct? And it is only MS Tool or are you having an issue in Mac application too?

Comment: @Udhy correct, it happens in any application where are you can create a new file not only Microsoft Office applications but also, for example, Notes and TextEdit.